# Hi, I am facing an issue in laravel livewire listner not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Survey;

use Livewire\Component;
use \App\Models\Section as SectionModel;

class Section extends Component
{
    public $questionnaireId;
    public $section;
    public $currentSection = 0;
    public $listeners = ['nextSection'];

    public function nextSection()
    {
        $this->currentSection++;
        $this->currentSection = $this->getSections($this->currentSection);
    }

    public function getSections($offset = 0)
    {
        $this->section = SectionModel::where('questionnaire_id', $this->questionnaireId)->offset($offset)->first();
    }

    public function mount($questionnaireId)
    {
        $this->questionnaireId = $questionnaireId;
        $this->getSections();
    }

    public function getSectionsProperty()
    {
        return $this->section;
    }
}
```

This is my componentOne.php

```
public function triggerNextSection()
{
    $this->emit('nextSection');
}
```

This is component-one.blade.php

```
<button wire:click="triggerNextSection"
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"> Continue
</button>
```

while click on the button continue, $currentSection value is increased by 1.

Same way I used this button and emit this event in componentTwo, Here not incrementing the value of $currentSection.

Can anyone please help how should I increment this varible value?

I tried to emit an event with passing parameters

Comment: Are you using Livewire 2 or 3? Because in 3, there's no longer an `emit` (see [upgrade guide](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#events))

Comment: You haven't passed any parameter to the emitted event! Pass the parameter and increment it there.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
protected $listeners = ['nextSection','mynextSection',];

public function mynextSection()
{
    $this->currentSection++;
    $this->currentSection = $this->getSections($this->currentSection);
}
```

Comment: When you do not use a key, the value given is both the event listener _and_ the action call. In the case you want a different action call, you need to make the array associative. This is very clearly stated in [the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#event-listeners). In your example, the method would only trigger if you called `emit('mynextsection')`